# More precise histogram in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

```py
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    plt.hist(rm['people'], range = [0,100000], color = 'b', orientation='horizontal')
    plt.title('Histogram')
    plt.xlabel('people')
    plt.ylabel('Frequency')
    plt.show()
```

[image: the chart I got]

Hello everyone

I got this code for histogram and it gives me this chart. I would like it to be same this chart

[image: a chart I want]

any help
Thanks

Comment: Don't specify a range in `plt.hist()`, there are not that many samples in your histogram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify `bins` to plot more bars:

```py
plt.hist(rm['people'], range = [0,100000], bins=500, color='b', orientation='horizontal')
```